# How i used graphics.h in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: xubuntu

```
sudo apt install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev pulseaudio-esound-compat libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package guile-2.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'guile-2.0' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package guile-2.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'guile-2.0-dev'
E: Unable to locate package pulseaudio-esound-compat
```

Comment: Which guide do you follow? Which application do you need to compile? What is `graphics.h`?

Comment: Please could you edit this with what question you’re asking? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are following some guide from the web and it was written for older Ubuntu version.

Below is the adapted version for Ubuntu 21.10:

```
sudo apt install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.2 guile-2.2-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
```