# How to install graphics.h library step by step on ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: xubuntu

I want to install graphics.h library on UBUNTU 21.10 but I'm facing so many error Is there proper step by step commands guide for this?

Comment: Have you tried other solutions for the same problem here on Ask Ubuntu, [such as this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369669/how-i-used-graphics-h-in-ubuntu-21-10) which you already got an answer to and accepted the answer?  (This is a duplicate post basically)

Comment: Which guide do you follow? Which application do you need to compile? What is graphics.h?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes Accepting  but it's showing that some libraries are missing so i decided to start it in proper steps. if I get all steps I can easily follow that